# Today() Function in Google Sheets stuck at Midnight

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Regardless of the time zone I have set on my google sheets doc =TODAY() produces the date but the time stays at midnight 0:00.

I have checked the settings to ensure TODAY() is set to update on change, I have tried formatting the cell as date-time, etc. Nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: seems like you're just looking for the `=now()` function?

Answer (score 1):

what you need is timestamp script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) {                       // Sheet name
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { 
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
  "GMT+8", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");                    // Format
  nextCell.setValue(newDate);
}}}
```

---

how to deploy a script:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

now you can close the apps script tab/window and enjoy the timestamp script running automatically whenever you type something in A column B column gets timestamped

[image]

Comment: That updates my entire column. I am using an if statement basically saying if column A isnt blank then place TODAY() in column B.

When i tried NOW() anytime column B changed, the entire column updated.

Comment: do i throw this into the cell, or do i need to create this function formally somewhere else? Thank you!

Comment: @mhsmustang1 answer updated

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the =NOW() function, =TODAY() will just fetch the date. The default time when you transfer a regular date value to a time stamp is midnight.